# How do I plot points / vectors as points?

Tags: matlab, plot

```
p = [3,3]
plot(p, 'x')
```

This weirdly generates this:[image]

I'd like it to be a point at x=3/y=3 on the plot. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@mathematician1975 is right, but I feel like this requires a bit more explanation:

Like the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) states:

> `plot(Y)` plots the columns of `Y` versus the index of each value when `Y` is a real number.

so in fact this is not weird at all that `plot(p, 'x')` plots each value in `p` against its index, *i.e.* the points (1, 3) and (2, 3).

This is actually handy in some cases (when you want the x-coordiantes to be a running index), but not in yours. To plot point `p` correctly, use the syntax `plot(X, Y)`, that is:

```
plot(p(2), p(1), 'x')
```

(here I assumed that the y-coordinate is the first in `p`, but if it's the x-coordinates you can just swap the places of the input arguments).

In the general case, if `p` is a matrix with two columns (say, the first contains all y-coordinates and the second all x-coordinates), you can plot all points like so:

```
plot(p(:, 2), p(:, 1), 'x')
```

Comment: x is for me always the left coordinate in a point. I actually want to draw a line with the points I have, I think your approach wouldn't work that way right? Saying plot(pointA, pointB, '-') basically.

Comment: @Blub I say again: `plot(X, Y)` requires the first argument to be a vector of all x-coordinates, and the second argument to be a vector of all y-coordinates. Also, if you want a line, there is no need specifying the `'-'` in the command. Example: `plot([pointA(1) pointB(1)], [pointA(2) pointB(2)])`.

Answer (score 2):

You need vectors of each coordinate. For example:

```
x = [3,4]
y = [5,6]
plot(x,y,'x')
```

will plot the points (3,5) and (4,6)